# nginx php7.3 files download instead of execute - no .sock file to pass to php-fpm

Tags: nginx, centos7, php7

I've already tried multiple configurations in the nginx.conf.default file as referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them

Here is what my nginx.conf.default looks like:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root   html;
    #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;    
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;

}
```

Other posts will say I need to have this included:
`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`
But I obviously don't have that file nor that full path. /var/run only has php-fpm. I'm using Centos 7.7.1908 core

Comment: You should [configure PHP-FPM](https://linuxize.com/post/install-php-7-on-centos-7/#configuring-php-7-x-to-work-with-nginx) to use UNIX sockets. You can use `netstat -xlnp` to list the open UNIX sockets.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I followed the directions in the link to the tooth, but the same thing is going on. My netstat output shows php-fpm as 'listening' and both nginx and php-fpm services are active(running)

Comment: Did you check if the name of the socket is the same as in `netstat -xlnp`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz yes. netstat -xlnp returns: 
`unix  2  [ACC]  STREAM  LISTENING  37027   3048/php-fpm: maste   /run/php-fpm/www.sock`
I've updated my nginx.config.default to match that of that tutorial.